# why wx.html2 module is not exist?

Tags: wxpython, wx.html2

I used python version 2.7.1. then installed `wxPython2.8-win32-ansi-py27`

and I was import wx.html2 but python shell printed Import error.

```
ImportError: No module named html2
```

wx.html module is not exist.. how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The html2 module is not available in wxPython 2.8. It is new in wxPython 2.9. Note that you will need to import it like this:

```
import wx.html2
```

Comment: I find and installed wxPython 2.9.
so i import wx.html2, then no error. Thanks :D